How to access Route parameter in Custom validator in ASP.NET Core Web API?
I have implemented a custom model validator using data annotations, where I wanted to compare two dates and validate if one is greater than the other, or not.
It works fine in POST (create) endpoint. However, a problem arises with the PUT (update) endpoint.
Because in PUT method, we want to get one date from the database using the {id} which is in PUT endpoint.
public class Contract
{
    [JsonPropertyName("StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DateGreaterThan("StartDate", ErrorMessage="EndDate must be greate than start date.")]
    [JsonPropertyName("EndDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

internal class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _comparisonProperty;

    public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string comparisonProperty)
    {
        _comparisonProperty = comparisonProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // get your StartDate and EndDate from model and value
        DateTime StartDate = (DateTime)value;

        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_comparisonProperty);

        if (property == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Comparison property with this name not found");
        }

        var comparisonValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

        // perform comparison
        // This works in POST
        if (StartDate < (DateTime)comparisonValue)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("start date must be less than the end date");
        }
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Now in case of PUT, I want to get StartDate from 
        // the database querying the record using "id" 
        // (1234 in below example) from Route of endpoint
        // https://localhost:5001/mycontroller/1234
    }
}

I have tried many solutions, but none of them is close to this.
We can not do this validation in the controller as per the requirement from the business. It has to be model-based validation.

Hello, did you had the chance to check the solution? Did you able to implement what you're trying to achieve?

While attributes are only used for "small" validations without DI, you have to use a filter which to access objects from DI.
Microsoft already wrote the ActionFilterAttribute which can be subclassed.
In there, you can access routing parameters (the id), asynchronously validate them and then set the context.Result to short circuit the request.
See also

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#action-filters
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api#handling-validation-errors



Because in PUT method, we want to get one date from database using the
{id} which is in PUT endpoint. I have tried many solutions, but none
of them is close to this. We can not do this validation in the
controller as per the requirement from business. It has to be
model-based validation.

According to this scenario and description, since custom validation attributes don't have direct access to the DI container or route data, you need additional external service which would provide the necessary services (Checking database values from route data) and route information to the validation context.
In order to do that, it might be more elegant to create an external service. This service would take the parameter for validation and perform any necessary database operations. We would then call this service within the validation method. Within the validation context, we can grab the route parameter and pass it to the external service.
Let's have a look how we could implement that:
In order to simulate the scenario, I would use InMemoryContractService instead of actual DbContext, wihtin your scenario, you could your DbContext.
External Service:
 public interface IContractService
 {
     DateTime GetStartDateById(int id);
     void AddContract(int id, DateTime startDate);
 }

As said earlier, we need a service which will be callied from the model validator while a put request invocked, and from the ID, we will call following service.
public class InMemoryContractService : IContractService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, DateTime> _contracts = new();

    public DateTime GetStartDateById(int id)
    {
        return _contracts.ContainsKey(id) ? _contracts[id] : DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    public void AddContract(int id, DateTime startDate)
    {
        _contracts[id] = startDate;
    }
}

Note: Call your DbContext to check your value inside the service. I have used InMemoryContext to simulate the test for quick.
Updated Model Validator:
public class DateGreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _comparisonProperty;

    public DateGreaterThanAttribute(string comparisonProperty)
    {
        _comparisonProperty = comparisonProperty;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = (IHttpContextAccessor)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor));
        var contractService = (IContractService)validationContext.GetService(typeof(IContractService));

        
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
        {
            var routeData = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetRouteData();
            if (routeData.Values.ContainsKey("id"))
            {
                var id = int.Parse(routeData.Values["id"].ToString());

                var startDate = contractService.GetStartDateById(id);
                DateTime endDate = (DateTime)value;

                if (endDate <= startDate)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("EndDate must be greater than StartDate.");
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}

Note: If HttpContext is null, it is likely a POST request, so skip route data retrieval.
Program.cs:
Inject the IContractService external service within the program.cs.
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IContractService, InMemoryContractService>();

Output:





Note: You could refer this official document for additional details.
